# How to connect my macbook to a Wi-Fi network?

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro, network

[image: There's network]

Using inSSider I see the eduroam network. Yet Wi-Fi doesn't detect it yet. Why could it be?

Comment: How do you know WiFi doesn't detect it?

Comment: the Wi-Fi window reads no network selected (and also from Join other network...).

Answer (score 2):

It may be that the network doesn't broadcast it's SSID (tools like inSSider can pick up the name other ways). Try clicking **Join Other Network** and entering the details manually, see if that works.

Comment: Didn't work either. It's a broadcasting network. Other macbooks find it.